# EhCache with spring data + JPA\Hibernate, Caching entities behaviour

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa, ehcache

Our project is a spring 4 project with mySQL DB, tomcat cluster and a load balancer. we use JPA for our entities. 
A new requirement demands we will 2nd level cache our "Node" entity.

This "Node" objects are behaving exactly like a tree, (there is a root, and each node can have references to many other nodes)

We would like that each tomcat in the cluster will have a cache for all the objects of the "Node" class.

We would like to cache them via the ehcache\hibernate methodology.

Since caching is pretty new to us, (especially the behavior when using clustered \ replicated cache) we have some questions:

Lets say the cache contains the following (A-Z are nodes) :

MyNode.id:1       references the Nodes: (A-B-C)

MyNode.id:2       references the Nodes: (D-B-F)

Now lets say that the Node object B is changed

1) will ehcache now invalidate both entries (1 & 2) ?

2) we are using spring data with repositories update queries, will ehcache be aware of updates we execute through spring data repositories?

3) same question as 2 with the addition that the repository executes a "nativeQuery = true" in the repository

4) will clustering replication of the ehcache here will work?